# /boot out of space for upgrade

Tags: debian, boot, apt

I'm trying to upgrade from Debian Stretch to Bullseye and running through the apt update process. I can't get past the new kernel install due to insufficient space on /boot. I've done the main suggestion, which is to `apt autoremove` and clear out all unused kernels/images. My boot partition is 90mb... terribly small, but was fine for older releases. The newer kernels are just bigger.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            4.0G     0  4.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs           803M  8.7M  794M   2% /run
/dev/sda3        75G   12G   60G  17% /
tmpfs           4.0G     0  4.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           4.0G     0  4.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1        86M   68M   14M  83% /boot
tmpfs           803M     0  803M   0% /run/user/0
```

Output of `fdisk -l /dev/sda`

```
Disk /dev/sda: 80 GiB, 85899345920 bytes, 167772160 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000adc37

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            63    192779    192717 94.1M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2        192780   8000369   7807590  3.7G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3       8000370 167766794 159766425 76.2G 83 Linux
```

Output of `free`

```
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         8217852      406260     5607664       29928     2203928     7091000
Swap:        3903788           0     3903788
```

There are only two images in boot now:

- initrd.img-4.19.0-21-686-pae (which is currently loaded)
- initrd.img-5.10.0-16-686-pae (this is what is trying to get configured)

```
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.140) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-16-686-pae
pigz: abort: write error on <stdout> (No space left on device)
E: mkinitramfs failure pigz 28
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-16-686-pae with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
```

Is there a straight forward way to resize, or change the boot location??? This is a virtual machine so I don have access to be in front of the system if it can't boot and I cant risk getting stuck.

Any recommendations? I know my way around linux, but mostly with the help of the internet.

Comment: Add the results of `df -h` to your question, please. I've done plenty of resizing with **Gparted**, which you would need to download as an ISO, then reboot the VM into it. Just make a copy of the VM beforehand, it case you need to quickly restore it.

Comment: What about moving the location of /boot to / and reinstall GRUB? Is this possible?

Comment: In theory, that should work; never tried it myself, haven't used anything but UEFI in ages.

Comment: What is your `/dev/sda2`? If it is swap, how large is it, how much RAM do you have, and are you using hibernation/sleep mode? If `sda2` is your swap, physically immediately after `sda1` and you could reduce it, then it might be easy to extend your `/boot`. Please *edit your question* to add the output of `fdisk -l /dev/sda`.

Comment: 1. **full backup** 2. boot from live CD, e.g. System Recure 3. Gparted

Comment: I've added more info @telcoM. I am not using hibernation. And to reiterate, I don't have access to this machine other than `ssh` so I can't boot from CD or other live install.

Comment: Solved via https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/710578/decrease-swap-to-extend-boot-partition