# Decrease swap to extend /boot partition

Tags: debian, boot, partition

I'm trying to upgrade a Linux system (Buster to Bullseye) but have run out of space on my boot partition. Is there an easy way to decrease the size of my swap (by 500MB) so that I can extend the boot partition? Is this possible without a reboot? I do not have physical access to this server, only `ssh`.

```
Disk /dev/sda: 80 GiB, 85899345920 bytes, 167772160 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000adc37

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            63    192779    192717 94.1M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2        192780   8000369   7807590  3.7G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3       8000370 167766794 159766425 76.2G 83 Linux
```

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        8294768      413896      974208       93464     6906664     7040816
Swap:       3903788        1068     3902720
```

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov that's somewhat true, and somewhat isn't! yes, the swap partition needs to be unmounted, reduced in size (from the beginning), and re-initialized as swap, then reactivated. But the boot partition can stay mounted while you increase its size, and on ext4, btrfs, xfs, … you don't even have to unmount it to increase the size of the file system.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov actually, there is a way to reload partition table in even when some partitions are mounted. You can even extend root parititon live, if the file system supports live resize. So your comment is *completely wrong and misleading*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just disable swap (it is not much used currently):

```
swapoff
```

Then remove swap partition and extend the boot partition; you may use `growpart` for that, you even don't need to unmount it. The create new partition for swap in the free space, create new swap space:

```
mkswap -F /dev/sda2
```

and update `/etc/fstab` with new swap information. Most likely you'll need to update an UUID with whatever `mkswap` printed; you can also look it up again by running `blkid`.

Then activate new swap:

```
swapon -a
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Was able to resize `/boot` and continue the upgrade. Rebooted just fine into Bullseye.